# Webpack without eval

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I realise that by using eval, webpack implements lazy parsing, but is there a config option I can use to embed the actual javascript rather than a string to be eval'ed?

Use case:

1. I have an Angular SPA that runs across several Smart TV platforms (Samsung, LG, etc).
2. Webpack 'require' works fine on most platforms but on some older devices, the modules fail to initiate
3. My best guess is that eval'ing a very large module string, crashes the device due to the amount of resources it takes up
4. I would like to continue to use webpack and module eval'ing on the devices where it does work, but embed the actual javascript on devices where it doesn't

Comment: Parsing large JS in a `<script>` tag probably isn't any faster than `eval`.

Comment: That's fine, but speed is not the problem.  The problem is that the app fails to launch on old devices and I think that's due to eval.

I'm looking for the least painful way to get the app to launch.  If there's an option I can set rather than changing everything to embed all the scripts, HTML and CSS, I'll take it!

Comment: So that I can concentrate my efforts in the right place, does it sound like a raw script loader is what I need?